# Android dynamic imageview's side by side in a relative layout

Tags: android-layout

I would like to seek your help regarding a requirement in my project.I have an application which will pick imageview from gridview and add it to another layout(this layout has relative layout as parentview).Every thing works fine, but one imageview is overlapping with other.

Instead I want imageviews to sit in my main layout side by side.

I came to know that using linear layout and setting orientation to vertical or horizantal we can achieve it  but in my project I must implement relative layout as per my application overall design.

Could any one please provide your inputs or an example.

Thanks & Regards,
Aditya.J